# Save Button Status

Tags: ios, swift, button

I'm starting to create a favorite `button` for my project and i need some help...

I have created a `button` and already programmed it to switch `image` when `tapped` right here:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //create a new button
        let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        //set image for button
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        //add function for button
        Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        //set frame
        Favoritebutton.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 35, 35)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

    }


    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    }
```

It works perfectly but as of right now if i quit the app the `button` does NOT save the status if its `selected` or not . I heard you can achieve this with `NSUserDefault` but i don't know how to implement this so i would love to get some help with it :)

I am using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not specific to the iPhone or Xcode. Please do not add irrelevant tags. You should read the descriptions of those tags to know when to properly use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy. In UserDefaults you can store boolean value without any problem.

In viewDidLoad you check value for your key like this.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let buttonIsSelected = defaults.bool(forKey: "keyForIsButtonSelected") // If no value exists for this key then false is returned

button.selected = buttonIsSelected
```

Inside your button function remember to save your status.

```
sender.selected = !sender.selected

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

defaults.set(sender.selected, forKey: "keyForIsButtonSelected")

defaults.synchronize() // Save your defaults, can also move this part of code to applicationWillTerminate
```

For Swift 2.3 use this.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let buttonIsSelected = defaults.boolForKey("keyForIsButtonSelected") // If no value exists for this key then false is returned

button.selected = buttonIsSelected
```

Inside button function.

```
sender.selected = !sender.selected

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.setBool(sender.selected, forKey: "keyForIsButtonSelected")

defaults.synchronize() // Save your defaults, can also move this part of code to applicationWillTerminate
```

Comment: Do not needlessly call `synchronize`.

Comment: Could be called on applicationWillTerminate, but if user exits app (and there is no synchronize in code) just after changing button defaults won't be updated (saved).

Comment: I'm Getting This Error :  `Use of unresolved identifier 'UserDefaults'` I'm using Swift 2.3 by the way @Adamsor

Comment: @Adamsor Only call `synchronize` in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. That's it. Not needed anywhere else.

Comment: @Newbie Questions Ohh then use 'NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("keyForIsButtonSelected")' and 'NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(button.selected, forKey: "keyForIsButtonSelected")'. They just renamed class (removed NS) and changed some methods.

Comment: Can you update you answer please because copying from the comment gives me troubles :\

Comment: @NewbieQuestions Sure, question updated for Swift 2.3

Comment: I still get This Error:  `Use of unresolved identifier 'UserDefaults'` both  inside the button action and in view did load

Comment: @NewbieQuestions Yeah, sorry, I just noticed during copying I lost NS prefix for UserDefaults. I updated post again, just use NSUserDefaults class instead of UserDefaults.

Comment: Ok Its working Perfectly now , Just changed all `UserDefaults` to `NSUserDefault` Thanks you !

Comment: I have another thing I'm pretty stuck with this favorite button I'm working on if you can ,I will ask another question very soon and any help will be appreciated @Adamsor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129748/discussion-between-adamsor-and-newbie-questions).

Answer (score 1):

for swift 3 it will be next:

```
//save value
UserDefaults.standard.set(selected, forKey: "lButtonSelected")
//then on next launch restore it
let selected = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lButtonSelected")
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the value in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(selected, forKey: "buttonStatus")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

And to retrieve the value from `NSUserDefaults`:

```
let buttonStatus = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "buttonStatus")
```

Comment: Do not needlessly call `synchronize`.

Comment: @rmaddy true, he could call synchronize when app enters background

Comment: That's the only time anyone should call `synchronize`.